# Relation between Alphabet and number in Mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql, sql, alphanumeric

Why does 'a' precede any integer in a column with both int and string and max, min or avg operations.

Query Context:-

```
select max(col1),max(col2),min(col2),avg(col3) 
from 
(
select 1 as col1, 2  as col2, 3  as col3 
union select 5, 6, 7 
union select 7, 8, 9 
union select 0, 1, 2
union select 1, 2, 3
union select 'a','b','c'
) as result_set;
```

Result:-

```
| max(col1) | min(col2) | avg(col3) |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|         a |         1 |      4.25 |
```

SQLfiddle Snippet:-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24fc37/1

Comment: love the way your fiddle doesn't match the published code and your published code doesn't produce the published result.

Comment: Yes, I am desperately looking for answers and the only answer I got was inclined towards "all" keyword. so I am constantly tweaking the fiddle.

Comment: Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little surprised that the columns are strings rather than numbers.  Under many circumstances, when number and strings are combined, the resulting type is a number -- and that would turn the `'a'` into `0`.

That said, you are getting string ordering.  And that presumably follows the ASCII character set.  In this character set, the digits (such as `'1'`) have lower "alphabetical" ordering than letters.

Unfortunately, the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) is not clear on what the rules for types are with `UNION ALL`.  There seems to be a bias toward strings, which is different from an arithmetic computation (`0 = 'a'`, for instance, returns "true", because `'a'` is converted to a number).